# Need some advice in SOQL

Tags: soql

I need some ideas, I have a MasterObject which has zip code information.

Table structure is:

zipcode Text(5)
Minzip Text(4)
Maxzip Text(4)
CountName Text(25)

**Zipcode
    Minzip
    Maxzip
    CountyName**
  
  
    98052
    1000
    2000
    Orange County
  

    98052
    2001
    3000
    Deleware County
  

    98053
    1000
    3000
    Franklin County

if user enters 98052-1821.
There are two row for 98052 but 1821 range falls between Minzip: 1000 and Maxzip: 2000.

i need to get the Orange country information. Is is possibel to write a SOQL query for this condition.

for Ex: SELECT Id, CountyName__c from MasterObject Where Zipcode = '98052' and (Minzip > '1821' and Maxzip < '1821') this is the logic i am expecting.

Comment: Why not Franklin County? There is some overlap... pretty unclear how you would handle collision behavior but regardless you will need to query all candidate `MasterObject` records and then use some Apex to select the correct one (if any). Likely not possible just with SOQL.

Comment: Hi Adrian, 1821 falls in Min and Max range of first row. Its basically we want to minimize the total number of rows for zip info for that  we are using Min Max option.

Comment: You're missing my point, 1821 also falls between 1000 and 3000. You're also going to have problems with, for instance, 'a' > '1821', so you need apex for stronger typing.

Comment: In my example I have mentioned Zipcode = '98052' I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use comparison operators in your soql SELECT statement. [Refer here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm)